# Use Certificate Autoenrolment with third-party Certificate Authority

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, certificate-authority, pki

Is it possible to setup Windows Domain to use Certificate Autoenrolment and third-party Certificate Authority?

We think that it can be done in Windows Server 2008 only but don`t know exactly, please help.

**References:**

We find this article ["Setting up Autoenrollment for Windows clients with EJBCA"](http://www.ejbca.org/howto.html#Setting%20up%20Autoenrollment%20for%20Windows%20clients%20with%20EJBCA). But it look like "first step" and not for usage in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 2003 environment it isn't possible, because lack of standard approach. But with Windows 2008 there are new APIs and integration points, so it can be done.